# How can I run background code when a notification is executed with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-local-notification

I am using `flutter_local_notification` and `workmanager` plugins in order to run some background code when a notification is generated (only Android). This is how flutter_local_notification is initialised:

```
final StreamController<ReceivedNotification> didReceiveLocalNotificationSubject = StreamController<ReceivedNotification>.broadcast();

Future<void> init() async {
    await _configureLocalTimeZone();

    notificationAppLaunchDetails = await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails();
    if (notificationAppLaunchDetails!.didNotificationLaunchApp) {
      selectedNotificationPayload = notificationAppLaunchDetails!.notificationResponse?.payload;
    }

    const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
    AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');

    InitializationSettings initializationSettings = const InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
    );
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
        initializationSettings,
        onDidReceiveNotificationResponse:
            (NotificationResponse notificationResponse) {
          switch (notificationResponse.notificationResponseType) {
            case NotificationResponseType.selectedNotification:
            case NotificationResponseType.selectedNotificationAction:
              // if (notificationResponse.actionId == navigationActionId) {
                selectNotificationSubject.add(notificationResponse.payload);
                selectedNotificationPayload = notificationResponse.payload;
              // }
                didReceiveLocalNotificationSubject.add(
                  ReceivedNotification(
                    id: notificationResponse.id!,
                    title: notificationResponse.actionId,
                    body: 'stuff',
                    payload: notificationResponse.payload,
                  ),
                );
              break;
          }
      },
      // onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse: notificationTapBackground,
    );

    _notificationsEnabled = await _isAndroidPermissionGranted();
    _notificationsEnabled = await _requestPermissions();
    _configureDidReceiveLocalNotificationSubject();
  }
```

and this is the code that gets executed with Workmanager:

```
void _configureDidReceiveLocalNotificationSubject() {
    didReceiveLocalNotificationSubject.stream
        .listen((ReceivedNotification receivedNotification) async {
          var title = receivedNotification.title ?? 'UNKNOWN';
          Workmanager().registerOneOffTask(
            "my.simpleTask",
            "my.simpleTask",
            inputData: <String, dynamic>{
              'string': title,
            },
          );
        });
  }
```

Currently I have two problems with that code:

- the Workmanager's task is run only when the user tap the notification
- the Workmanager's task won't be executed if the app is terminated by the user first, even if the notification is generated (and tapped)

How can I make the Workmanager's task to be executed as soon as the notification is generated (without the user tapping) with the application terminated or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i assume you are scheduled local notification and execute some function in there.

TL:DR

- first: scheduled local notification **not able to execute function in background**

eg:

```
int randomInt = Random().nextInt();
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
    0,
    'scheduled notif with int $randomInt',
     ....
```

when you are registed this notif, you will get `randomInt`, and then on the notification it will show the `int` that you get first time its scheduled. which means, its only show notification,`Random().nextInt` is not executed.

- secondly,

```
void _configureDidReceiveLocalNotificationSubject() {
    didReceiveLocalNotificationSubject.stream
```

stream function will be terminated too after the apps is killed. except you are bring it into  foreground. the stream will keep listening any changes.

---

> How can I make the Workmanager's task to be executed as soon as the
> notification is generated

I think you are missed on this part. the correct way is:
Register `Workmanager` and then inside the `callback` function, you can generated `local notification`.

- register your WM in your `initState`

```
Workmanager().registerOneOffTask(
  "task-identifier",
  simpleTaskKey,
  initialDelay: Duration(minutes: 30), // you can use this delay for scheduling
);
```

then in the callback funtion generete local notificaiton

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager().executeTask((task, inputData) {
   // you function execute here
   // eg: final tempInt = Random.nextInt();
   // then we can use the tempInt 

    show local notification function here
    return Future.value(true);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Are you saying that the "scheduler" that drives should be the one from WM and not the one from flutter_local_notification, as only the former can execute tasks when the app is offline?

Comment: In that case I do not need to use "zoneSchedule" from f_l_n and show the notification straight away as soon as VM receive the own notification.

Comment: yes correct. we need `callback` to execute function in the background. FLN have `onTapHandler`. which means function will execute only when user tap on the notif.

Comment: but different with FCM, the it has  a `_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler`. with this we can execute function after received notification.

Comment: works thanks! BTW FCM allows you to create more complicated timeframes for scheduling for example: if time is between 8.00AM and 8.00PM and it is Tuesday or Friday then send notification hourly?